# Triangular band matrices with entries $\pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, terminology, algebraic-graph-theory

This lower triangular matrix ( with entries $\pm 1$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1   &  0  &   0   &  0  &   0  &   0 \\ -1 &    1 &    0 &    0  &   0    & 0 \\ 1  &  -1  &   1 &    0  &   0   &  0 \\-1 &    1 &   -1 &    1  &   0   &  0 \\1 &   -1 &    1 &   -1  &   1     &0 \\ -1 &    1 &   -1  &   1  &  -1    & 1  \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

has some interesting properties. The main diagonal is all $1$ and the other diagonals are signed but constant. I  wish to know if these kind of matrices are studied in the literature. Is there a name for such matrices? What is shown here is a $6\times 6$ version, but this generalizes to any square dimension.

For starters, this is the inverse of a constant band matrix. That is.,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1    &  0   &   0   &   0   &   0  &    0 \\1   &   1  &    0   &   0   &   0  &    0 \\ 0  &    1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0 \\0   &   0   &   1    &  1   &   0   &   0 \\0  &    0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0 \\0   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1\end{pmatrix}^{-1} &=& \begin{pmatrix}  1   &  0  &   0   &  0  &   0  &   0 \\
    -1 &    1 &    0 &    0  &   0    & 0 \\
     1  &  -1  &   1 &    0  &   0   &  0 \\
    -1 &    1 &   -1 &    1  &   0   &  0 \\
     1 &   -1 &    1 &   -1  &   1     &0 \\
    -1 &    1 &   -1  &   1  &  -1    & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

I am aware that band matrices are well studied in the literature, but curious about work done on their inverses and their properties/structure etc., Walsh, Hadamard, Sierpinski, any such connections?

Specific questions that I am looking for are:

$1.$ Is there a name for such matrices?

$2.$ Is there any prior work done on such matrices, especially geometric or graph theoretic connections?

$3.$ Any known matrix related to these family of matrices?

Comment: These happen to be special examples of [Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Toeplitz_matrix), if that's useful.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to see if there is finer than Toeplitz:-). I can see this behaving like a discrete integration in $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ (well that is when we go further down to finite filed where $-1$ effectively becomes $1$). I am pretty sure, it has special structures even in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Some special **constant** matrices have their own names, such as Hilbert matrix or Kac matrix, but names are far more often given **not** to such constant matrices, but to **classes** of matrices, such as Toplitz matrices, Vandermonde matrices, Cauchy matrices, Hankel matrices, Hessenberg matrices, Hadamard matrices, Hermitian matrices, circulant matrices, stochastic matrices, $M$-matrices, triangular matrices or diagonal matrices.

The matrix in your question is a constant matrix, not a class of matrices. It is just the inverse of a unipotent Jordan block. Maybe it has a name, but I don't think it is special enough to deserve one.